# Making a page for every product with it's ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

My question is that i want the easiest way to make a page for every product with his ID that stored before to the database

Example :

Home/Products/"The product ID in the database"

And this link have to display "Details" for the product ^

The purpose is when i add a new product a new page automatically created with the product id.

the action code in the controller :

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddArticle(NewsData art)
    {
        var ArticleID = art.ArticleID;

        using (MatrodyEntities db = new MatrodyEntities())
        {
            db.NewsData.Add(art);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        return View(art);
    }
```

The RouteConfig :

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us your existing route definitions.

Comment: i have put the routeConfig

Comment: Where exactly are you facing the problem in implementing this. please specify.

Comment: I believe you want to open the `Details` of each product in your View. Create your link like this in your View where you are displaying your products: `@Url.Action("Products", "Home", new { id=product.Id })` . This would generate something like this when you click on it: Home/Products/{product.id}

Comment: Create one Details page in which the ID will be passed from URL(as you mentioned) as as per the ID content of that page will change and will get it from DB by that ID.

Comment: If ID is Auto Increment then `var ArticleID = art.ArticleID;` need to write after save changes and before returning the view.

Comment: @RahulSharma No.

Comment: @RahulSharma your solution in the other question fixed this too thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so in order to make a link for a CRUD operation based on a parameter, you can either use AJAX to POST your data with a parameter or you can use `Html.ActionLink` which does not POST but rather creates an anchor tag.

1) Using ActionLink with a parameter:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
        //Additional data
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Home", new { id = item.id})
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

In your `Home` controller:

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id) {//Your logic}
```

Please note that if you are using the default `RouteConfig` then ensure that you are sending `id` as your parameter or you can create your own routing as required.

2) You can also use AJAX to POST to your Controller. You can do something like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
        //Additional data
            <td>
               <a href="#" data-id="@item.id" onclick="confirmDelete(this)"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

And in your AJAX:

```
    function confirmDelete(event) {
        var recordToDelete = $(event).attr("data-id"); //Get our current file id here

        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record") == true) {
            //Prepare our data
            var json = {
                id: recordToDelete
            };

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("DeleteFile", "Home")',
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { "json": JSON.stringify(json) },
                success: function (data) {
                    if(data == "success") {
                        alert("Successfully deleted selected file");
                        location.reload();
                    }                        
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert("Could not delete selected file. Please try again!");
                },
            });
        }
    };
```

And finally in your Controller:

```
//Delete a file based on the ID that you get from your View
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult DeleteFile(string json)
{
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    try
    {               
        dynamic jsondata = serializer.Deserialize(json, typeof(object));
        string id = jsondata["id"];
        if(id != "")
        {             
            int getid = Convert.ToInt32(id);
            //Call your db or your logic to delete the file
            DatabaseAccess data = new DatabaseAccess();
            string result = data.DeleteFile(getid);

            if(result.Equals("Success"))
            {
                return Json("success", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            else
            {
                return Json("fail", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }                     
        }
        else
        {
            return Json("notfound", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
       return Json("dberror", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```